# if $E$ is locally compact, then the closed ball $\bar B(0,1)$ is compact.

Tags: normed-spaces, compactness

I'm having some trouble proving the following:

> Let $E$ be a normed space. Then if $E$ is locally compact, then the closed ball $\bar B(0,1)$ is compact.

I tried to show that any open cover of $\bar B(0,1)$ has a finite subcover by rescaling the open sets, creating a new open cover for some closed ball $\bar B (0,\epsilon)$, but this didn't work. I have no idea how to approach this problem. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rough outline is as follows:

1. By local compactness, there must be some compact neighbourhood of $0$, i.e. some compact set $K$ such that there exists an open set $U$ with $0 \in U \subseteq K$.
2. As the balls form a basis, there exists some $\varepsilon$ with $B(0,\varepsilon) \subseteq U$. Then also $\overline{B}(0,\frac{\varepsilon}{2}) \subseteq U \subseteq K$.
3. The intersection of a compact set and a closed set is compact, which means that $\overline{B}(0,\frac{\varepsilon}{2}) \cap K = \overline{B}(0,\frac{\varepsilon}{2})$ is compact.
4. By rescaling we then show that if $\overline{B}(0,\frac{\varepsilon}{2})$, then $\overline{B}(0,1)$ is also compact.